# What is wrong with this ifelse-command? (rows get excluded that don´t match the if-statement)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I wanted to exclude rows with participants who show error rates above 15%
When I look at the error rate of participant 2, it is for example 2,97%

```
semdata[2,"error_rate"]
[1] "2,97"
```

But if I run this ifelse-statement, many participants get excluded that don´t display error rates (but others not, which is correct).

```
15% (e.g., this participant 2).
for(i in 1:NROW(semdata)){
#single trial blocks
ifelse((semdata[i,"error_rate"] >= 15),print(paste(i, "exclusion: error rate ST too high",semdata[i,"dt_tswp.err.prop_st"])),0)
ifelse((semdata[i,"error_rate"] >= 15),semdata[i,6:NCOL(semdata)]<-NA,0)
#dual-task blocks
# ifelse((semdata[i,"error_rate"] >= 15),print(paste(i, "exclusion: error rate DT too high")),0)
# ifelse((semdata[i,"error_rate"] >= 15),semdata[i,6:NCOL(semdata)]<-NA,0)
}
[1] "1 exclusion: error rate ST too high 6,72"
[1] "2 exclusion: error rate ST too high 2,97"
[1] "7 exclusion: error rate ST too high 2,87"
[1] "9 exclusion: error rate ST too high 5,28"
...
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Totally ignorant when it comes to R, but it looks like you should convert the value to a number before comparing and that you’re now comparing the values as strings. When comparing strings, “2,97” > “15”

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks!

Comment: A further issue is that you simply use ifelse wrongly. You seem to assume that it is equivalent to if {…} else {…} but it is not. Study help(“ifelse”).

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings here.

```
"6,72" > 15
#[1] TRUE
```

You should convert the data to numeric first before comparing which can be done by using `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", "6,72"))
#[1] 6.72
```

This can be compared with 15.

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", "6,72")) > 15
#[1] FALSE
```

For the entire column you can do -

```
semdata$error_rate <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", semdata$error_rate))
```

Comment: Yes, apparently this was the problem. However, the last command for the whole column unfortunately did not work. I got the error that there are only 0 replacements, but 119 columns.

Comment: Is your dataframe called `semdata` and does it have column called `error_rate` (`semdata$error_rate` works ?) ? What is the exact code that you used to give the above error?